# texreg on panelmodel (plm) object; additional gof information

Tags: r, latex, plm, texreg

How do I customize the goodness of fit (gof) in a [texreg](/questions/tagged/texreg) call?

I have some [plm](/questions/tagged/plm) models I want to display, but I only get `"Num. obs.", "Adj. R^2",` and `, "R^2"` (see working example below). I would howver like to all display small `n`, `T`, `F-statistic`, and `p-value`, all stuff I get in the default `summary()` call.

A example of what I got. First some data and needed packages,

```
# install.packages(c("wooldridge", "plm", "texreg"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(wooldridge) 
data(wagepan)
library(plm)
```

Second, some models,

```
POLS <- plm(lwage ~ educ + black + hisp + exper+I(exper^2)+ married + union +
            factor(year), data = wagepan, index=c("nr","year") , model="pooling")

RE <- plm(lwage ~ educ + black + hisp + exper + I(exper^2) + married + union +
          factor(year), data = wagepan, index = c("nr","year") , model = "random") 

FE <- plm(lwage ~ I(exper^2) + married + union + factor(year), 
          data = wagepan, index = c("nr","year"), model="within")
```

Third, my current  [texreg](/questions/tagged/texreg) call and its output,

```
# library(texreg)                      
texreg::screenreg(list(POLS, RE, FE), custom.coef.map = list('married' = 'Marrtied', 'union' = 'Union'))
#> ================================================
#>            Model 1      Model 2      Model 3    
#> ------------------------------------------------
#> Marrtied      0.11 ***     0.06 ***     0.05 *  
#>              (0.02)       (0.02)       (0.02)   
#> Union         0.18 ***     0.11 ***     0.08 ***
#>              (0.02)       (0.02)       (0.02)   
#> ------------------------------------------------
#> R^2           0.19         0.18         0.18    
#> Adj. R^2      0.19         0.18         0.06    
#> Num. obs.  4360         4360         4360       
#> ================================================
#> *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

I did try adding `, include.fstatistic = TRUE`, but it seems as I can't get it that way. It is as I need some additional customization.

I am aiming for something like this,

```
#> ------------------------------------------------
#> Obs.  (N)   4360         4360         4360       
#> Indiv.(n)    545          545          545       
#> Time  (T)      8            8            8       
#> R^2           0.19         0.18         0.18    
#> Adj. R^2      0.19         0.18         0.06    
#> F-stat       72.458       68.4124      83.8515  
#> P-value        (2.22e-16)   (2.22e-16)   (2.22e-16) 
#> ================================================
#> *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hack it using `texreg::extract()`.

For getting the "small `n`" we need a small function first.

```
getIndex <- function(fit){
  # extracts number of factor levels of index variables
  # from raw data used in models
  index.names <- as.character(as.list(summary(fit)$call)$index)[-1]
  if (length(index.names == 1)){
    df.name <- as.character(as.list(summary(fit)$call)$data)
    index.df <- get(df.name)[, index.names]
    length(unique(index.df))
  }
  if (length(index.names == 2)){
    df.name <- as.character(as.list(summary(fit)$call)$data)
    index.df <- get(df.name)[, index.names]
    cbind(length(unique(index.df[, 1])), 
          length(unique(index.df[, 2]))) 
  } else {
    stop("no index variables specified in model")
  }

}
```

Then go on extracting.

```
fv.1 <- summary(POLS)$fstatistic$statistic  # get F statistic
pv.1 <- summary(POLS)$fstatistic$p.value  # get p value
ns.1 <- getIndex(POLS)[1]  # get small n
tm.1 <- getIndex(POLS)[2]  # get times

library(texreg)
ex.1 <- extract(POLS)  # extract coefficients and GOF measures
ex.1@gof.names <- c(ex.1@gof.names[1:3],"Indiv.(n)", "Time (T)", 
                    "F-stat", "P-value")  # the GOF names
ex.1@gof <- c(ex.1@gof[1:3], ns.1, tm.1, fv.1, pv.1)  # the GOF values
ex.1@gof.decimal <- c(ex.1@gof.decimal[1:3], FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)  # numeric or integer

fv.2 <- summary(RE)$fstatistic$statistic
pv.2 <- summary(RE)$fstatistic$p.value
ns.2 <- getIndex(RE)[1]
tm.2 <- getIndex(RE)[2]

ex.2 <- extract(RE)
ex.2@gof.names <- c(ex.2@gof.names[1:3],"Indiv.(n)", "Time (T)", 
                    "F-stat", "P-value")
ex.2@gof <- c(ex.2@gof[1:3], ns.2, tm.2, fv.2, pv.2)
ex.2@gof.decimal <- c(ex.2@gof.decimal[1:3], FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)

fv.3 <- summary(FE)$fstatistic$statistic
pv.3 <- summary(FE)$fstatistic$p.value
ns.3 <- getIndex(FE)[1]
tm.3 <- getIndex(FE)[2]

ex.3 <- extract(FE)
ex.3@gof.names <- c(ex.3@gof.names[1:3],"Indiv.(n)", "Time (T)", 
                    "F-stat", "P-value")
ex.3@gof <- c(ex.3@gof[1:3], ns.3, tm.3, fv.3, pv.3)
ex.3@gof.decimal <- c(ex.3@gof.decimal[1:3], FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

**Yielding**

```
> screenreg(list(ex.1, ex.2, ex.3))

=======================================================
                  Model 1      Model 2      Model 3    
-------------------------------------------------------
[TRUNCATED...]
-------------------------------------------------------
R^2                  0.19         0.18         0.18    
Adj. R^2             0.19         0.18         0.06    
Num. obs.         4360         4360         4360       
Indiv.(n)          545          545          545       
Time (T)             8            8            8       
F-stat              72.46        68.41        83.85    
P-value              0.00         0.00         0.00    
=======================================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Take a look into e.g. `str(extract(FE))` to apply this for additional GOFs.

To wrap it into a function take a look at code in @Neal Fultz's answer.

Comment: Waw, it really does require quite a lot of _hacking_ to get there. I had imagined there would be some simple called or command I had overlooked. Thanks for demonstrating this approach!

Comment: Welcome! Hope I didn't reinvent the wheel, I also couldn't find a simple command, though.

Comment: I'll hold out for some hours and see if someone can point to a wheel. Thanks again.

Comment: Would you be up for editing your answer to include the `545 Indiv.(n)`? If so I'll be happy to award you the bounty.

Comment: Sure, I'd be honored. It was quite a hack, the difficulty was, that small `n` and `time` variable nowhere seems to be saved within `summary(model)`, so we have to consult the raw data to obtain them.  I've tested `getIndex()` with some other data, too, and should be working in most cases. Test the function with e.g. `plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)` vs. `plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris, index="Species")`.

Answer (score 4):

Following up on @jaySF answer, create your own extract function which wraps the default, and register it:

```
custom_extract_plm <- function(model, ...) {
  s <- summary(model)
  ex.1 <- texreg:::extract.plm(model, ...)

  fv.1 <- s$fstatistic$statistic
  pv.1 <- s$fstatistic$p.value

  ex.1@gof.names <- c(ex.1@gof.names, "F-stat", "P-value")
  ex.1@gof <- c(ex.1@gof, fv.1, pv.1)
  ex.1@gof.decimal <- c(ex.1@gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)

  ex.1
}

setMethod(texreg:::extract, signature = className("plm", "plm"), custom_extract_plm)
```

Now you get an F-statistic:

```
> texreg::screenreg(list(POLS, RE, FE), custom.coef.map = list('married' = 'Marrtied', 'union' = 'Union'))

================================================
           Model 1      Model 2      Model 3    
------------------------------------------------
Marrtied      0.11 ***     0.06 ***     0.05 *  
             (0.02)       (0.02)       (0.02)   
Union         0.18 ***     0.11 ***     0.08 ***
             (0.02)       (0.02)       (0.02)   
------------------------------------------------
R^2           0.19         0.18         0.18    
Adj. R^2      0.19         0.18         0.06    
Num. obs.  4360         4360         4360       
F-stat       72.46        68.41        83.85    
P-value       0.00         0.00         0.00    
================================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Comment: Thank you for contribution to the discussion. I wonder if you would have time to include small `n`,  what is `Indiv. (n)`  above, in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility using `huxreg` from my `huxtable` package. You will also need the `broom` package installed.

```
library(huxtable)

ht <- huxreg(POLS, RE, FE, 
      coefs = c("Married" = "married", "Union" = "union"), 
      statistics = c("Obs. (N)" = "nobs", "Adj. R^2" = "adj.r.squared", 
        "F statistic" = "statistic", "P value" = "p.value"))
```

The number of time units is not in `broom::glance`, so we add it manually - here is a simple way:

```
Ts <- purrr::map_int(list(POLS, RE, FE), list(pdim, "nT", "T"))
ns <- purrr::map_int(list(POLS, RE, FE), list(pdim, "nT", "n"))
ht <- insert_row(ht, c("Time (T)", Ts), after = 6)
ht <- insert_row(ht, c("Indiv. (n)", ns), after = 6)
ht

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     (1)             (2)             (3)       
              ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
  Married          0.108 ***       0.064 ***       0.047 *     
                  (0.016)         (0.017)         (0.018)      
  Union            0.182 ***       0.106 ***       0.080 ***   
                  (0.017)         (0.018)         (0.019)      
              ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
  Obs. (N)      4360            4360            4360           
  Indiv. (n)     545             545             545           
  Time (T)         8               8               8           
  Adj. R^2         0.187           0.178           0.061       
  F statistic     72.459          68.412          83.851       
  P value          7.250e-186      5.813e-176      1.655e-156  
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05. 

Column names: names, model1, model2, model3
```

This will automatically print out as TeX/HTML within a Rmarkdown document. You can edit it to add rows, columns and further formatting.

Comment: Waw, thanks for demonstrating how your [tag:huxtable] package can answer my question. Maybe I should used that! I am exporting to LaTeX. Two quick questions. How did you find the names `statistic` and `p.value`, asking as I still to identify small `n`, what I called `Indiv.(n)`. Second, what was your motivation for writing [tag:huxtable]? I take you have a link? :)

Comment: Those names are from `broom::glance`. The small `n` isn't available there... you can find it in `pdim(model)$nT$n`, and I learned that by looking through the code of `plm:::print.summary.plm`!

Comment: Updated my answer to add the individuals

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!  I am however a bit reluctant to reward the bouncy to this answer as I, in my initial question, asked for a `texreg`  solution.  That is not to say that you haven't answered my question!